# Why is np.exp(5*1j)**1j not equal to np.exp(1j*5*1j)?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get theta in $\exp (i \theta)$ without wrapping it back to $-\pi$. Couldn't I simply raise it to $i$? I'm thinking $-(\ln((\exp(i\theta))^i))$ should give me $\theta$? What am I doing wrong here. For example using Python's numpy library `np.exp(5*1j)**1j` is not equal to `np.exp(1j*5*1j)`. `1j` here is $i$.

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing here, so we can't say what is wrong.  Please provide more details.  The lack of MathJax makes it much harder to read as well.

Comment: What is '1j'? Clarify your notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a complex exponentiation problem, you're asking about $\left ( e^{5i} \right )^i$ vs. $e^{5i(i)}$. The problem is that complex exponentiation is actually ambiguous: $\left ( e^{5i} \right )^i$ is by definition $e^{i \log \left ( e^{5i} \right )}$ and there are an infinite number of logarithms of $e^{5i}$, given by $5i+2\pi i k$ for any integer $k$. Presumably numpy is picking a logarithm other than $5i$ which is why you aren't getting $e^{-5}$. $e^{5i(i)}$ meanwhile is just $e^{-5}$ and that's it.

I don't have a Python install handy, but when I do this in Matlab I find log(exp(5*j)) is giving me $5i-2\pi i$ which means that exp(5*j)^(1*j) ends up giving $e^{-5+2\pi}$. (Ignoring floating point errors all around.) The explanation is that Matlab is using the principal logarithm so the imaginary parts go from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and the principal logarithm of $e^{5i}$ is indeed $5i-2\pi i$.